# Dismiss View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have an `UIViewController` in `storyboard` that is not connected to `UINavigationController`. It is presented when user taps on **local notification**, now I want to dismiss it on button press and go back to my root view controller that is in `UINavigationController`.

Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: You can use an unwind segue or simply call `self.dismiss(animated:, completion:)`

Comment: how did u present it when the notification was tapped? was it a push or was it opened as a model? is your navigation controller used while presenting or not?

Comment: I present it through App Delegate :           UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
        UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"xyzVC"];
        self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: I do this in" didReceiveLocalNotification"

Answer (score 0):

You can call dismiss method on the presented controller to close it and go back to where you were.

**Objective-C:**

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

For Navigation Controller, if you want to go to root view controller use in the completion block of dismissViewController method:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**Swift:**

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: where is other part bro ***now i want to dismiss it on button press and go back to my root view controller that is in navigation controller***

Comment: I am using this code        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
N.B. my view controller is not connected to Navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like on your button click,

```
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController*)self.presentingViewController;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.m call inside the method:- **didReceiveRemoteNotification** open the notification view..

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController. storyboard; 
NotificationView *objNoti = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Notificationview"]; 
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:objNoti animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And after that working notification back button press to dismiss view...

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
 UIViewController *vc = weakSelf.presentingViewController ;
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
                 UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController*)vc;
            [nc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

First present it like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard; UIViewController *newViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"xyzVC"]; 

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now when you will **dissmiss newViewController** you will automatically navigated to your **root view controller**

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I want through the following:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController.storyboard;
UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerID"];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController = rootViewController;
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] makeKeyAndVisible];
```